# How to nest a function inside a function in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have some test code I am working on as I am just learning Python and I was wondering how you nest a function inside another function in Python (if it is even possible). Here is the code I am working with.

```
import turtle

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

def square(length, angle):
    my_turtle.forward(length)
    my_turtle.left(angle)
    my_turtle.forward(length)
    my_turtle.left(angle)
    my_turtle.forward(length)
    my_turtle.left(angle)
    my_turtle.forward(length)

def repeat(length, angle):
    square(length, angle)
    my_turtle.left(angle)
    square(length, angle)

repeat(50, 45)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code you posted? Is there a specific problem you're having?

Comment: What do you want to nest and why?

Comment: What do you mean by "nest"?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to _call_ a function inside of another function?

Comment: Presumably this isn't the indentation in your code. Seeing as you're asking about nesting functions, it may be kind of important to know which functions are indented how much.

Comment: You need to properly indent your code. As written, it won't do very much of use.

Comment: @ChristianDean  I may be saying it wrong but basically I want to be able to place the square function inside of the repeat function so that I do not have to retype everything.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen You are correct, my code is indented differently in my editor. Here is the code in pastebin https://pastebin.com/1S5943gE

Comment: Why not edit the code here instead?

Comment: So... what's wrong with the code you have, and how do you expect nesting one function inside another to help with anything?

Comment: @user2357112 Nesting it will let me repeat the code without having to type it. I have the square(50,45) my_turtle.left(45) square(45,50) in there about 6 times.

Comment: ...no, nesting wouldn't do that at all. You need to learn about loops.

Answer (score 2):

First - your indentation is wrong.

Second - in a square, you do not get to choose the angle (it's kind of a done deal).

Third - `for` loops are a good thing:

```
def square(length):
    for i in range(4):
        my_turtle.forward(length)
        my_turtle.left(90)
```

Then you can use that from another function like

```
def three_squares():
    for i in range(20, 80, 20):   # gives [20, 40, 60]
        square(i)
        my_turtle.left(10)
```

Python also lets you pass functions to functions, like

```
def multi(times, inter_angle, action, *args):
    # This will let you choose **what action** to repeat
    for _ in range(times):
        action(*args)
        my_turtle.left(inter_angle)

multi(2, 45, square, 50)   # draws two squares offset at 45 degrees
```

While you can define a function inside a function, as demonstrated by @cdlane, it is a less common thing to do; usually only if (a) you are binding values from the outer function into the inner one or (b) if you want to make sure no other functions can call the inner one.

Comment: When the iterator is not used, it's often customary to call it `_`

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen: I am aware of that, and use it myself, but did not feel like explaining that extra complication ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's fair enough. No worries - I'll leave my comment up on the off chance someone has an epiphany because of it

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen: there - now we have one of each!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title (Which is what people who search for this will find), Python will let you nest functions one within another:

```
def first():
    print("in first")
    second()
    def first_a(): #You can only access this function within the "first" function.
        print("in a of first")
    first_a()

def second():
    #This function CANNOT ACCESS first_a() directly; it will return a NameError
    print("in second")


#You CANNOT ACCESS first_a() here outside of the functions either, same error.   
first()


# Prints "in first", "in second", and "in a of first"
```

Nesting functions can be really useful if you are aware of how to use them correctly.

In my opinion, a loop such as what @Hugh Bothwell has already provided would be the better way to go, so hopefully you will be able to figure out what you're wanting to accomplish.

If you still want to nest functions, @cdlane has provided a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering how you nest a function inside another function in
>   Python

I'm not sure why everyone is picking on your lack of a loop, to the point of calling it an ***issue***.  It's not clear why you want to nest these functions, but you certainly can do it:

```
import turtle

def repeat(length, angle):

    def shape(length, angle):
        my_turtle.forward(length)
        my_turtle.left(angle)
        my_turtle.forward(length)
        my_turtle.left(angle)
        my_turtle.forward(length)
        my_turtle.left(angle)
        my_turtle.forward(length)

    shape(length, angle)
    my_turtle.left(angle)
    shape(length, angle)

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

repeat(50, 45)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Your code got it working, but my previous code was drawing 4 octagons, so to make it back to the octagons how would I edit the code to draw octagons?

Comment: @Odinosuarus, I've corrected my code to mimic your original.

Comment: We're talking about the lack of a loop because the questioner has repeatedly expressed a belief that nesting functions would somehow prevent them from having to retype as much. Nesting functions has no such effect; what the questioner needs is a loop.

Comment: @user2357112, the initial discussion centered on a loop in the `square()` function which does not require a loop.  But the discussion has evolved much since then.  The need for a loop in the `repeat()` function still seems up in the air as I've no idea what the OP is attempting to draw.  Do you?

Comment: Some kind of square...octagon...thing? No clue.

Comment: I am just playing around with Python, my original code drew an octagon. I personally don't care what it draws.